# How to shorten url which contains Id and parse that id when the url is clicked

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using linking to link my react-native app to my domain
https://www.example.com/
I am also passing an id which changes based on the article shared
So the shared url looks like:

```
https://www.example.com/12234503
```

What i want to do is shorten this using firebase dynamic links(I can only use this)

### I have no clue how to pack this id into the `createShortDynamicLink` function or how to access the id i got when i will open this short link in my app

#### This is what my code without firebase links looks right now

Accepting the url

```
   componentDidMount() {
     Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
     Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
       if (url) {
         Linking.openURL(url);
       }
     }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
     DeepLinking.addScheme('https://');


     DeepLinking.addRoute('www.example.com/:id', (response) => {

       this.props.navigation.navigate('Article',{id:response});
     });
```

So i open the app  and then take the use to the page where i use the id to load the article

Sharing the Url using react-native-share

```
   let shareOptions = {
       title: "Share This Story",
       message: "Read This Awsome Article:",
       url: "https://www.example.com/"+this.state.id,
       subject: "Share Link"
     };
     Share.open(shareOptions).catch((err) => { err && console.log(err); });
```

## Can you give me a rough outline of code that shows me how can i implement the same using firebase dynamic links

### All this is because i want to shorten the shared link

I have a domian to confige

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
url: `https://www.example.com/${this.state.id}`
```

Comment: The code above is working properly, what i want is to recreate the same code using google dynamic links